# Find sequence of functions such that $||f_n||_1\to0 , ||f_n||_{\infty}\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to  Find sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions such that $\underbrace{||f_n||_1}_{n \to \infty} $ tends to zero,and$ \underbrace{||f_n||_{\infty}}_{n \to \infty}$ tends to ${\infty}$?  Really I got stuck on this, an d I don not have a clue "how to start". I think about $$f_n=n^2\chi_{[0,\frac1n]}$$but I am not sure, that I am in a right way.Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your question and title don't match. Do you want the $1$-norm to approach $1$ or $0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you, Can you suggest more example?  or judge my example please?

Comment: @GossipM|: thank you for notifying me. I correct it. but now " Kavi Rama Murthy"  example's 1-Norm tends to 1?

Comment: Your example doesn't work because $\|f_n\|_1 \to \infty$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy: Can you please show me how $$\|f_n\|_1 \to \infty$$ ?

Comment: I am sorry for the first time typo. but I am sure that question is $$||f_n||_1\to0 , ||f_n||_{\infty}\to \infty$$

Comment: @Khosrotash  In your example the integral  is the area under the rectangle with side length $\frac{1}{n}$ and height $n^{2}$. So $||f_{n}||_{1} = n$ which goes to infinity in your example. If you switch the side length to $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and the height to $n$ then it will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_{n}=n χ[0,\frac{1}{n^{2}}]$.

Supremum of $f_{n}$ is n which goes to infinity.

The 1 norm is  $\frac{n}{n^{2}}$ which goes to 0.